# C# Unable to track entity of type because primary key property is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a User table and a UserProfileImage table that is linked together.

This is the User table structure

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public override bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; } = true;
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    
    public UserProfileImage UserProfileImage { get; } = new UserProfileImage();

}
```

This is the UserProfileImage structure

```
public class UserProfileImage
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

I have linked them in the dbcontext like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOne(a => a.UserProfileImage)
    .WithOne(b => b.User)
    .HasForeignKey<UserProfileImage>(b => b.UserId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

However, when I try to add a new user, I get this exception:

> Unable to track an entity of type 'UserProfileImage' because primary
> key property 'Id' is null.

May I know what does this mean? I am not adding a new entry to UserProfileImage at the moment.

Comment: `I am not adding a new entry to UserProfileImage` - yes you are, for you have specified `UserProfileImage { get; } = new UserProfileImage();`.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize that. I have been setting the relationships the wrong way. Thank you for your help. Can you put that as your answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to fix your classes:

```
ublic class User : IdentityUser
{
   ......
    public  string UserProfileImageId  { get; set;}

   [ForeignKey(nameof(UserProfileImageId ))]
    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual UserProfileImage UserProfileImage { get; set;}

}

public class UserProfileImage
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
     ......
    [InverseProperty("UserProfileImage")]
   public virtual User User { get; set;}
}
```